# What is the deps folder in a Tauri project?

Tags: typescript, rust, svelte, tauri

The deps folder in the target/debug folder for a Tauri project. What is and why is it so large. On my mac it's approx 1.30GB. Also can it be deleted?

I am using a M2 Mac Pro if that makes any difference...

P.S. I am using Svelte as a frontend.

Any information is appreciated :)

I have looked into it but I couldn't find any information about it...